# VBA Sumifs multiple open workbooks & criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sum all data in column from an external workbook, there are no NA values present and my formula returns only zeros.

Sum range: Global file column EU4:EU
Criteria 1 Range: Global File column L4:L
Criteria 1: ForecastBI: Column B
Criteria 2 Range: Global File column K4:K
Criteria 2: ForecastBI: Column C
Criteria 3 Range: Global File column KY4:K
Criteria 3: ForecastBI: Column D

```
Dim Master As Excel.Worksheet: Set Master = Application.Workbooks(" 
Global_File.xlsm").Worksheets("data")
Dim LrHc As Long: LrHc = Master.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim LcHc As Long: LcHc = Master.Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 
+ 1

Dim ForecastBI As Excel.Worksheet: Set ForecastBI = 
Application.Workbooks("Actual.xlsm").Worksheets("Act")
Dim LrUpload As Long: LrUpload = ForecastBI.Cells(Rows.Count, 
"A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim LcUpload As Long: LcUpload = ForecastBI.Cells(2, 
Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

'''Sum range
Dim Fte1 As Excel.Range: Set Fte1 = Master.Range("EU4:EU" & LrHc)

Dim Country As Excel.Range: Set Country = Master.Range("L4:L" & LrHc)
Dim CountryCriteria As Range: Set CountryCriteria = ForecastBI.Range("B2:B" & 
LrUpload)

Dim Region As Excel.Range: Set Region = Master.Range("K4:K" & LrHc)
Dim RegionCriteria As Range: Set RegionCriteria = ForecastBI.Range("C2:C" & 
LrUpload)

Dim DB As Excel.Range: Set DB = Master.Range("KY4:KY" & LrHc)
Dim DBCriteria As Range: Set DBCriteria = ForecastBI.Range("D2:D" & LrUpload)

For x = x To LrUpload

If ForecastBI.Cells(x, 1) = Master.Cells(2, 55) Then
   Cells(x, 8).Value = Application.Worksheetfunction.SumIfs(Fte1, _
      Country, CountryCriteria.Cells(x, 2).Value, _
      Region, RegionCriteria.Cells(x, 3).Value, _
      DB, DBCriteria.Cells(x, 4).Value)

Else: ForecastBI.Cells(x, 8) = 0

End If

Next x
```

Comment: what is the specific question/issue?

Comment: The formula is only returning zeros, there should be different numbers populating.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do things like this, at least in the beginning, is to record the steps, as you click through each one.  I just did it, and came up with this, below.

```
Sub Macro1()

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIF([Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!RC:RC,""A"",[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!RC[1]:RC[5])"
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A10")
    Range("A1:A10").Select

End Sub
```

Using the Sumproduct function, as an alternative, I came up with this.

```
Sub Macro2()

    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMPRODUCT(([Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!RC=""A"")*([Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!RC[1]:RC[5]))"
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A10")
    Range("A1:A10").Select

End Sub
```